# I have an appointment scheduling application I am trying to create

Tags: java, mysql

I am stopped at a point where I need to have a popup inform the user their appointment is in 15 minutes. When I run the code I get a sql error. Any help is appreciated.

I have put in real times in place of the variables and it works fine. When I put the variables back in I get the error listed below.

```
public static Appt apptIn15Min() {
Appt appointment;
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
ZoneId zid = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime zdt = now.atZone(zid);
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime ldt2 = ldt.plusMinutes(15);
String user = UserDB.getCurrentUser();
System.out.println(ldt);
System.out.println(ldt2);
System.out.println(user);
try {
    Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE start BETWEEN '" + ldt + "' AND '" + ldt2;
    ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.println(query);
    System.out.println("Lookup started");
    if(results.next()) {
        appointment = new Appt(results.getInt("aptId"), results.getInt("customerId"), results.getString("start"),
            results.getString("end"), results.getString("contact"), results.getString("type"),
            results.getString("location"), results.getString("contact"));
        System.out.println("Lookup Completed");
        return appointment;
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2019-07-29T21:59:28.709' at line 1 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2491) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2449) at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1381) at Builds.ApptDB.apptIn15Min(ApptDB.java:216) at Interface.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:135) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097) at Interface.LoginController.tryLogin(LoginController.java:72) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769) at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657) at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191) at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59) at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49) at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198) at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411) at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185) at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182) at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96) at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89) at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218) at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191) at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59) at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74) at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54) at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198) at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757) at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485) at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762) at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494) at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394) at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432) at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389) at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431) at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555) at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937) at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection. Dates are strings an must be inside single quotes.

Comment: `... + "' AND '" + ldt2;` Aren't you leaving something unterminated there?

Comment: `'" + ldt2 + "'";` - you forgot about the quote marks after the last date. But yeah, parameterised queries please...it would remove the risk of this kind of silly problem, and also protect you properly against injection attacks

Comment: By the way, your approach to booking appointments looks incorrect. You should not be adjusting to UTC and then going to `LocalDateTime`. Future appointments should be represented as a `LocalDateTime` (a date and time-of-day, but no zone/offset) paired with an intended time zone (`ZoneId`). No UTC involved there. Say 1 PM next January 23rd in Québec, so 2020-01-23 in `America/Montreal`. Store this in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. When building a schedule of actual moments, do: `ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( zoneName ) )` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Still no UTC needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your query string as the there is no closing single-quotation **after** ldt2

This is how your query should look like:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE start BETWEEN '" + ldt + "' AND '" + ldt2 + "'";
```

Also, I would recommend to use String.format() for String-formatting purposes instead of trying to concatenate such complicated strings.

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: He should just use `PreparedStatement` which prevents him from using such complicated `String`s but more importantly is safer against SQL Injection.

Comment: Indeed, PreparedStatement is another, or actually a better option.

Comment: I figured it was a simple mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## `PreparedStatement`

Just as an aside from Safeer Ansari's answer I will put an example of how to use  [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for this scenario and why it would be advantageous.

For `LocalDateTime` arguments, use [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object)).

The `Statement` and `String` can be rewritten like this:

```
Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
String query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE start BETWEEN ? AND ? ;";
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query)
statement.setObject(1,ldt);
statement.setObject(2,ldt2);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Notice how building the `String query` statement no longer requires any `String` concatenation and instead you use `?` as the location to set the variables to.  There are no downsides to using `PreparedStatement` over `Statement` when using a dynamic query.

**Note:**  I have not included any closing of resources or `exception` handling to keep the example simple. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for that chore.